# How do I deploy assets with hash in names via Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass

I have a big assets folder with images and fonts. These images and fonts are referred to in either scss-files or html-files. Those scss- and html-files are imported with webpack's `require` into js. How do I copy my assets folder to `dist` while adding a hash and somehow wiring it property where they are referred to? I need to put a hash on everything to prevent browser from using a wrong cached version if it's changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
output: {
  filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
}
```

instead of just

```
output: {
  filename: '[name].js',
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
}
```

as the [documentation mentions](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/). You can either use `[hash]` or `[chunkhash]`, the latter being chunk-specific.

Comment: This is a js-file with a hash. I need to add a hash to a folder of images and fonts. Actually js-files in my project already have a hash.

Comment: well, you can also use syntax like this in loaders like `css-loader`, something like `css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!postcss!sass?includePaths[]=`

Comment: This line of code seemingly makes no sense. Where do I read about it?

Comment: it's on the `css-loader` configuration page, look it up here: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader

Comment: for images you could use `file-loader` which has a similar configuration option `file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]` look it up here https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-webpack-loader

Comment: The answer is correct, but I just very poorly worded my question due to lack of knowledge in Webpack. In fact I wanted to dynamically load assets rather than import them on compile-time.